# Struct as argument in to a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, arguments

I have a problem when passing a Struct as an argument to a function. I have defined the struct as:

```
struct message{
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string msg;
    std::string timestamp;
    message(void)
    {
    }
    message(const std::string& recvbuf_msg,const std::string& a_timestamp) :
    msg(recvbuf_msg), timestamp(a_timestamp), id(++last_id)
  {
  }
};
```

and the fuction definition like this:

```
void print_msg(message *myMsg,std::string recv_usrn){
    cout << "#" << myMsg->id << " @" << recv_usrn << ": " << myMsg->msg << " at " << myMsg->timestamp << endl;
}
```

In the main I have used the function like this:

```
message myMsg;
string recv_usrn;
print_msg(&myMsg,recv_usrn);
```

And the problem is that it gives these errors:

> > C2065: 'message': undeclared identifier
> >
> > C2065: 'myMsg': undeclared identifier
> >
> > C2182: 'print_msg' : illegal use of type 'void'

Comment: Did you forget to include the declaration of `message`? Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: When I wrote 'message myMsg' it was just to make it clear that 'myMsg' was a stuct of type message. It was filled previously in the code.

Comment: To use the `message` structure, you must first define it. Is it defined before the definition (implementation) of the `print_msg` function? Is the structure defined before you define the `myMsg` variable before the call to `print_msg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for me it is working, are you putting every thing in same file..
This is working fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
struct message{
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string msg;
    std::string timestamp;
    message(void)
    {
    }
    message(const std::string& recvbuf_msg,const std::string& a_timestamp) :
    msg(recvbuf_msg), timestamp(a_timestamp), id(++last_id)
  {
  }
};

void print_msg(message *myMsg,std::string recv_usrn){
    cout << "#" << myMsg->id << " @" << recv_usrn << ": " << myMsg->msg << " at " << myMsg->timestamp << endl;
}

int main()
{
message myMsg;
string recv_usrn;
print_msg(&myMsg,recv_usrn);
}
```